# What is milliprice (it seems to be an extension of microprice)

Tags: high-frequency, market-microstructure

For computing the expected future price (on a small time scale) one can use micro price which is defined [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5h-i76er5AhVHMVkFHW6CAtoQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ma.imperial.ac.uk%2F%7Eajacquie%2FGatheral60%2FSlides%2FGatheral60%2520-%2520Stoikov.pdf&usg=AOvVaw36taz-xGo7AueJaAE3eeRB).

The definition of micro-price is

`S = Pa * Vb / (Va + Vb) + Pb * Va / (Va + Vb)`

where Pa is the ask price, Va is the ask volume, Pb is the bid price, and Vb is the bid volume.

And then I heard of milliprice which is located [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj624eU6ur5AhV2EGIAHWfXAf4QFnoECA4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.lsa.umich.edu%2Fseminars_events%2Ffileupload%2F4044_Microprice_Michigan.pdf&usg=AOvVaw23Q5Dtndl97Tb9Qnfs5l1y) but after reading the presentation I am still not sure how to compute it.  I understand it includes last trade price but that is about it.

Comment: Are you asking for an intuitive explanation of the milliprice concept or how to compute it? If the second (or both), it would be better if you narrow down your question a bit and provide more details in addition to the links (one ore more of the links may get broken in the future) and focus.

Comment: Your link appears to be paywalled.